# app.yaml configuration file -web application

Tags: google-app-engine

i created web application in eclipse3.5 I want to create app.yaml configuration file,where i create this file please guide me

Answer (score 3):

1. [Read the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html)
2. Open text editor.
3. Follow instructions in docs.
4. Save file.
5. Close text editor.